# Генератор случайных чисел в Java

Tags: java

Что нужно сделать, чтобы промежуток был 1-100, а не 0-99?

```
int q = (int)(100*Math.random());
```

Comment: Господи, я в шоке...

Comment: Возможно человек думал, что есть возможность это параметрически задавать

Comment: Эта штука вовсе не зовётся оператором.

Comment: автор мы вам будем помогать всем чем сможем, только боже упаси вас продолжать программировать после того как закончится учеба в школе/институте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

добавить 1:

```
int q = (int)(100 * Math.random() + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Зачем так сложно, есть проще:

```
Random rand=new java.util.Random();
int q=rand.nextInt(100)+1;
```

Comment: ну тут на самом деле спорно, что проще/короче

Comment: Целочисленные операции попроще будут...

Comment: В смысле вычисляется быстрее и в основном не за счет преобразования double (тип результата Math.random()) в int.